# Keep getting Segmentation Fault : 11 message in C++?

Tags: c++

The assignment is to search for a word inside a matrix (only left to right) by putting the word and starting point in the command line and return true if the word is there and false if it is not. Unfortunately, I continue to recieve a segmentation fault msg. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    cout << argv[i] << " ";
  }
  char word;
  argv[1] = &word;
  stringstream ss;
  string sWord;
  ss << word;
  ss >> sWord;
  int startRow = atoi(argv[2]);
  int startCol = atoi(argv[3]);

  int x, y;
  cin >> x >> y;
  cout << x << y << endl;
  vector < vector < char > > matrix;
  matrix.resize(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
    matrix.resize(y);
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
      cin >> matrix[i][k];
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++){
    if(matrix[startRow][startCol + i] != sWord[i]){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you *assigning* to `argv[1]`?

Comment: You first instinct should be to use a debugger for things like this. Start by reading [this](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf), for example, or really just [any one of these](https://www.google.fi/search?q=gdb+tutorial).

Comment: argv[1] is the word im searching for that is put in the command line, how else can i do it?

Comment: `std::string sWord = argv[1];` (assuming `argc` says there are enough parameters), but then use `sWord` instead of C string functions like `strlen` later.

Comment: Where does it crash and for what input does it crash?

Comment: I get this error msg when i try to compile now with that change:

no matching function for call to 'strlen'
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(sWord); i++){

Comment: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to
      'const char *' for 1st argument

Comment: Replace `strlen` with `word.size()` or `word.length()`.

Comment: Yes, when coding C++, you should use C++ string types and functions. Mixing in C things is just going to cause confusion and possibly UB. Get used to C++'s standard library from the beginning, and if you're anything like me, you won't look back.

Comment: still getting a segmentation fault with these changes: std::string sWord = argv[1]; int wordLength = sWord.length();

Comment: instead of all this: char word;
  argv[1] = &word;
  stringstream ss;
  string sWord;
  ss << word;
  ss >> sWord;

Answer (score 1):

You are calling strlen() on the address of a single char:

```
char word;
argv[1] = &word;

...

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++){
```

strlen() requires a null-terminated array of chars, since it only stops at the null-terminator '\0'.

Since the variable "word" is never actually set to anything, your char variable will not have a null-terminator, so strlen() will continue until it reaches a '\0' in memory, which in this case, seems to run beyond your program stack ("word" is a local stack variable, so its address points to your program stack).

I am not sure why you are assigning argv[1] to the address of a char variable, but this should answer your question on why your program is terminating unexpectedly.

Comment: dont I have to assign argv[1] to char, and do you have any solutions to this problem in mind? Do i need to make an array of chars for word for every letter and then just use that array in the final for loop?

Comment: @ThomasMolloy: Make your life easier.  Switch to using `std::string`.  Use `std::string::length()` to find the length of the string.  You can also use some of the other methods like `find` and `substr`.

Comment: still getting a segmentation fault with these changes:   

std::string sWord = argv[1];
  int wordLength = sWord.length();

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your matrix properly: 
Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
    matrix.resize(y);
```

your probably meant to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
    matrix[i].resize(y); //resizze "inner" vector
```